# How can I horizontally/vertically center a modal popup when the modal is sometimes bigger than the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I know how to center a modal with javascript but I run into a problem when the modal is taller than the viewport. The top of the modal will be hidden off the top of the screen.

Comment: So.. why dont you just get user's screen width and height, and adjust your modal by that result?

Answer (score 2):

You want to take

```
    (windowHeight - modalHeight) / 2
```

as top position of modal

```
    if (modalHeight < windowHeight) 
    else make top as 0 or may be 10.
```

I think you already explained this.

One possible issue is if you are using fixed positioned modal, the overflowed part wont show, In that case you should provide a fiddle or link to help you with your case.

For fixed positioned overflow, you can either make the modal max-height as 100% and show scroll bar in modal.
If the modal is a child of overlay, you might set max-height of overlay as 100% and use scrollbar on overlay instead.

If you are using absolute positioned modal, you will get the scroll bar for body.

pseudo code

```
top = (modalHeight < windowHeight)? (windowHeight - modalHeight) / 2 : 10 ;
```